# how to add values in single column of multiple rows in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, sql-query-store

I have a table customer and I added a new col address now I want to fill this address col a once for all the rows present in table

Comment: Please add your tried code and describe... read, how to ask good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

That should be a simple `UPDATE` without `WHERE` condition:

```
UPDATE customer
SET newcol = /* an arbitrary expression that can contain other columns and subqueries */;
```

Note that after the `UPDATE`, the table might have grown to up to twice its original size, because all rows have been modified, sou you might want to do this afterwards:

```
VACUUM (FULL) customer;  -- blocks the table while it is running
```